# OpenGL switching between ortho and perspective

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, sdl, game-engine

I have a tile engine using orthographic projection in immediate mode and I'm just trying to draw a 3d cube on top of my tile scene, in hopes that I can eventually incorporate 3d models into my engine instead of just sprites / textured quads. I would also like to make the tiles 3d for that slight bit of extra eye candy.. Hopefully I can eventually convert this to use modern OpenGL so I can take advantage of those extra features. Not on the top of my priority list at the moment. So on to the question.

I'm initializing OpenGL with this:

```
void initGL()
{
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glViewport( 0,0,SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT);

    //Initialize Projection Matrix
    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();   

    //Initialize Modelview Matrix
    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();       

    glOrtho(0,SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT,0,0,1);
    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_FASTEST);     
    //...setting some various other attributes, omitted for brevity...

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glClearColor( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
}
```

I have a function for drawing a cube that works.

```
void draw_cube()
{
     /* position object */
    glRotatef(30.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F);
    glRotatef(30.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F);    

    /* draw six faces of a cube */
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    ...vertices... (removed for brevity)
    glEnd();             
}
```

I made 2 functions for setting the 2d and 3d projection modes.

```
void set3d()
{
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glFrustum(0,SCREEN_WIDTH,0,SCREEN_HEIGHT, 0,1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}
void set2d()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0,SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT,0,0,1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}
```

For the sake of completeness, some ***pseudocode*** of my textured quad drawing..

```
pushmatrix();
translate();
rotate();
-translate();

glbegin();
...vertices
glend();
popmatrix();
```

So far I have managed to get the cube to draw on top of the tiles, but it disappears after approximately 1 second to never be seen again until I run the program again.

Basically what I'm doing in the main loop is this:

```
move objects around, process collisions, etc.

set2d();
draw textured quads, lines, text, etc. in 2d mode.

set3d();
draw_cube();
```

My question is: Why is the cube disappearing, and are there any errors in my set2d() and set3d() functions?

Comment: Have you tried calling `draw_cube()` first before you draw quads? Also, what depth are the 2D quads being drawn at? I think the cube is there, it's just behind your textured quads... maybe try just rendering the cube without the textured quads and see if it stays on screen.

Comment: your problem lies i think in glFrustum function, more specifically in zNear parameter. It NEVER should be equal to zero, and although the general rule is to make it small, you always have to be cautious with this; too short value of zNear WILL cause depth artifacts even in small models, a 0 will lead to singularities in mathematical calculations(basically, because of "divide by zero" kind of thing), which result, well, in complete disappearence of the image.

Comment: Well spotted Pavel. I'd also be inclined to increase the `farVal`. It's worth noting both values should be positive.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I did try drawing the cube first, and it didn't work. However I discovered that if I comment out the set2d() function the cube doesn't disappear, although nothing else is drawn other than a piece of a tile in the upper right hand corner which partially covers the cube after a second or so.

Comment: Your answer makes sense Pavel, but the cube doesn't draw at all if I change the zNear value of the glFrustrum call. First I tried 0.1 then I went all the way to 0.00000001 and it won't draw. I changed the zFar to 3. I also commented out the set2d() so there is nothing else drawing on top of the cube just to be sure, and it draws fine if the zNear is 0, but if I change it I get nothing. I'm using a standard cube example. I tried a couple of examples. They both work at zNear 0, and don't work at anything else. Any ideas?

Comment: That initGL function of yours has mismatched `glPushMatrix` calls, if it's called a few times, you'll overflow the matrix stack. Have you checked `glGetError()`?

Comment: Your projection matrices are setup incorrectly. One of them will produce right-handed projection and the other will produce left-handed. If you use polygon facet culling then the winding orders are going to be reversed when you switch between matrices and you will need to either change the winding direction OpenGL uses for front-face or cull the other face. This actually applies to any GL operation that can differentiate between rasterized sides (e.g. stencil, vertex lighting, culling, fragment shading). Also, as others have mentioned, you cannot use 0.0 for near with a perspective projection.

Comment: Thank you Trillian, I removed the pushmatrix() calls from my initGL() function. I will try glGetError() momentarily. Thank you Andon, I changed set3d() to use glFrustum(0,SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT,0, 1.0F,3.0F);.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have quite a few problems in this code, too many to list in comments in fact.

1. Your projection matrices are changing the handedness of your post-projected coordinate space, which will affect polygon winding.

   - Stick to a single handedness, unless you want to reverse the direction used for front- / back-facing polygon facets (`glFrontFace (...)`) - it is CCW by default, but you will have to change it to CW when you use `set3d (...)` to maintain consistent behavior.
   - This problem arises because you have the Y-axis going different directions
2. The behavior your are describing, where the object appears briefly and then disappears is indicative of an issue with your matrix stack.

   - Are you calling `initGL (...)` more than once in your software? You will run into a stack overflow if you do this enough times since you needlessly push the current matrix onto the stack and never pop it off.
3. You cannot use **0.0** for zNear with a perspective projection matrix, this will result in wonky math during the perspective divide step that comes *after* transformation to clip-space; the depth buffer will not work correctly.

   - In fact, `glFrustum (...)` will generate a `GL_INVALID_VALUE` error and do exactly ***nothing*** if you pass a value ≤ **0.0** for zNear. On a related note, `gluPerspective (...)` will not do this since it is not actually part of OpenGL, but it is equally invalid behavior to pass such a value to `gluPerspective (...)`.

Comment: Thank you Andon, and everyone else who answered. I had the Y-axis reversed in glFrustum() by mistake. Thank you for pointing that out. I am not calling initGL() more than once. I did double check all my code and found 2 places where I had glEnd() and glPopMatrix() reversed by mistake. In regards to point 3: I was able to get the cube to draw on top of the tiles by using glFrustum(0,SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT,0, -1,1); in set3d() and glOrtho(0,SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT,0,-1,1); in set2d(); so apparently you can have the zNear set to <0 in glFrustum. Probably not right, but it works for now.

Comment: and i think you can drop glPushMatrix() calls from initGl() altogether.. Keep in mind, thta minimum required size of matrix stacks in OpenGL is not that big, and for GL_PROJECTION matrices you really have only like 2 guaranteed spots in the stack...